# Jenkins not send any build status to Github

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I know there were a lot of conversations to this topic but any of those was helpful to me. So what I'm doing is configuring Jenkins CI to work properly with Github. 
We want next:

1. When someone creates new PR or add commit to existing PR, Github
   triggers Jenkins build.
2. During build is processing we want to see status - `pending`
3. Merge button should be disabled till build is completed
4. After build is completed, we want to see what is the status of that build - `successful` or `failed`

Right now, only step `1` works correctly but we can't figure out what is the problem with Jenkins requests to Github!

Also in console output I see error: 
`ERROR: Build step failed with exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get remote GH repo for project1 build` and don't know what is the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated !

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub Pull Request Builder , go to trigger setup -> Update commit status during build [image]

Comment: I did it, but nothing happens. What I see in console at the end ( after build is done) is some output:
`ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get remote GH repo for project1 build`